# Mechanism for alcohol synthesis via terminal acetylene reaction with sodium amide followed with epoxide and protonation

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

[image]

If anyone can give me some guidance here, it'd be much appreciated. I know the NaNH2 would dissociate and the NH2- base would deprotonate the terminal acetylene. I'm assuming the resultant product would act as some sort of nucleophile which would open the ring of the epoxide. The Na+ would form an ionic bond with the negatively polar oxygen after which the acid would protonate said oxygen, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The final structure is wrong. Count carbons. Missing a CH2.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you are on the right track and answered the question. First, NaNH$_2$ is used as a base to deprotonate the terminal alkyne (see this [Reagent Friday](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/07/29/reagent-friday-sodium-amide-nanh2-2/)). Second, the generated nucleophile opens the epoxide in an S$_\mathrm{N}$2 fashion, usually adding to the lesser substituted carbon which in your case yields a quaternary alcohol after acidic workup (see also [Opening of Epoxides With Acid](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2015/02/02/opening-of-epoxides-with-acid/)).

(Note: Indeed you are missing the CH$_\mathrm{2}$-group where the nucleophile attacks in the final structure)